# Attaching a ClearQuest DWO to a Jira Story

Tags: clearcase, jira, jira-plugin, clearquest, code-collaborator

Our company uses tools in their workflow:

- IBM Rational ClearQuest (For bug and feature change tracking)
- IBM Rational Clearcase (Subversion)
- Code-Collaborator (Code-Review software)
- Atlassian JIRA (Story management)

Right now our current workflow is as follows:

1. A view and activity is created to make changes to the existing code. When the activity is created, in-house tools create a new DWO to track the state of the work being performed (working, in inspection, ready-to-submit).
2. In order to submit the code back into the main stream, a code-inspection using Code-Collaborator is started and a link to the code-review is attached in the DWO.
3. The review is completed, the code is submitted into the stream and the DWO is closed.

We are currently missing a key relationship between the DWO and the Jira story. Just linking the Code-Collab review to a Jira story is not considered to be as strong as linking the DWO to a Jira story (suggesting the "Defect Tracking and ALM Tools" by code-collaborator is not an attractive option. It may also introduce higher licensing costs to our company).

As an example, when I review a set of stories from Jira I have the DWO numbers so that I can collect the code-reviews to summarize code changes in a document.

**My Question**:

Is it possible to push the DWO number into a Jira story and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a custom integration:

- using ClearQuest API (as in [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=260680)) to attach Jira information
- using the Jira CLI (JCLI, as in [this article](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface)) to push information (like a ClearQuest DWork Order uid) to a Jira item (in your case, a story).

I never seen that kind of integration implemented, but using those CLI, I guess it could be possible.

Comment: Thanks again Von. Sounds like we'll be looking into the Jira CLI to see what it can do for us.

Comment: Jake88, please contact us. We provide an add-on tool that summarizes code changes in ClearCase, and now we work to integrate it with 3rd-parties. It sounds we can give you what you need from the perspective of ClearCase baselines\streams\labels - contact beta (@) gomidjets dot com